# Cannot assign a value to an object that is inside an array

Tags: javascript

I am writting a logic to control online users in a chat. I  don't know why can't I update an object that is in an array. How can I change the object property. I am a little lost because I expected it to work, I don't know what is wrong.

My code:

```
 var users = []; 
 var isOnline= false;

  //check if the user is present in the users array, if it is just update the socket id
   for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {

       if (users[i].HId == usuario.id) {
         console.log("new id " + client.id );
         console.log("id before " + users[i].id);
         usuarios[i].id == client.id; // value doesn't change
         console.log("id after " + users[i].id);

        isOnline= true;
     }


  }

 //if the user is not present add him to the array
 if(!isOnline)
  users.push({ name: user.nome, HId: user.id, id: client.id });
```

[image]

Comment: Remove one `=` from the line. This is a comparison operator instead of an assigment operator: `usuarios[i].id = client.id`

Comment: You should be using `users[i].id = client.id;`

Comment: Everyone stop answering. This question should just be closed as a typo.

Comment: @Barmar Honeypot question for easy, breezy, beautiful karma :P

Comment: Ok, I will remove this question. I couldn't spot the error. Sorry! Thanks

Comment: Programming for 10 years I can rarely remember a time when used a comparison for an assignment operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your affectation

it should be

```
     usuarios[i].id = client.id; // value doesn't change
```

instead of

```
     usuarios[i].id == client.id; // value doesn't change
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
     usuarios[i].id == client.id; // value doesn't change
```

To

```
     usuarios[i].id = client.id;
```

`==` is a logical equals.  Thus `usuarios[i].id == client.id` is a boolean expression.  `usuarios[i].id = client.id` is an actual assignment.

Answer (score 0):

== (or === which you should be using) results in either true or false. Its a boolean check. What you want for assigning values is a single equals

```
usuarios[i].id = client.id; // assigns a value
```